# auto resize images

Tags: images, php, jquery

let say there is a folder comes with over 100 large items images and I want to resize it all images by putting specific size number between height and width in the form.

MY question is there is software or codes out there for me to learn that once input the size number and will automatic resize all images and save in somewhere!
it can be use jquery, php or anything.

Comment: ImageMagick is usually fine for things like that

Answer (score 0):

[irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/) will not read sizes from anywhere and will not convert each image differently though it can convert all images to one size that you specify at the time of conversion. Go to Menu - Batch Conversion.

Answer (score 0):

MS PowerToys has a module where you can run:

fits in 640 x 480 or any other size you want.

It is free from Microsoft.

[PowerToys Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/)

[PowerToys Software](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/image-resizer